# AngularJS minification

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bundling-and-minification

EDIT 3 : The problem was absolutely not dependencie injection but with angular-mock. See 'Pierre Gayvallet' answer below.

I'd like to avoid using ngmin, ngAnnotate or others grunt plugin when i minify my code.

So i'm using inline annotation like this :

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // some code
}]);
```

It works fine except for one thing : config.

```
// routes configuration
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', function($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {

    // enable http caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home/:filter?', {
            templateUrl: 'assets/app_components/app/views/home.html'
        })

        // default redirection
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

}]);
```

is minified to :
EDIT 2

```
app.config(["$httpProvider","$routeProvider", function(a, b) {

    // enable http caching
    a.defaults.cache = true;

    b
    .when('/home/:filter?', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/app_components/app/views/home.html'
    })

    // default redirection
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });

}]);
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks for any help

EDIT 1: Add grunt file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// project configuration
grunt.initConfig({

     pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Tasks

        clean: {
            site_prod: ['dist'],
        },

        copy: {
            dev_to_prod: {
                files: [
                    // includes files within path
                    {expand: true, cwd: 'site_dev/', src: ['*.html'], dest: 'dist/'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: 'site_dev/assets/app_components/app/views/', src: ['*.html'], dest: 'dist/assets/app_components/app/views/'}
                ],
            },
            keep_fonts_font_awesome: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'site_dev/assets/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/',
                src: '**/*',
                dest: 'dist/assets/app_components/fonts/'
            },
            keep_dist_fonts_bootstrap: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'site_dev/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-af/dist/fonts',
                src: '**/*',
                dest: 'dist/assets/app_components/fonts/'
            },
            keep_dist_img_bootstrap: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'site_dev/assets/bower_components/bootstrap-af/dist/img',
                src: '**/*',
                dest: 'dist/assets/app_components/img/'
            }
        },

        less: {
            less_to_css_prod: {
                files: {
                    'dist/assets/app_components/css/default_css.css': 'site_dev/assets/app_components/css/default_css.less'
                }
            }
        },

        replace: {
            less_in_html: {
                src: ['dist/*.html'],
                dest: 'dist/',
                replacements: [
                    {
                        from: '\.less',
                        to: '\.css'
                    },
                    {
                        from: 'stylesheet\/less',
                        to: 'stylesheet'
                    }
                ]
            },
            remove_mock_angular: {
                src: ['dist/assets/app_components/app/app.js'],
                dest: 'dist/assets/app_components/app/app.js',
                replacements: [
                    {
                        from: '\'ngMockE2E\',',
                        to: ''
                    },
                    {
                        from: '"ngMockE2E",',
                        to: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        jshint: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'site_dev/assets/app_components/app/**/*.js']
        },

        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';',
            },
            app: {
                src: ['.tmp/concat/assets/app_components/css/default_css.css', 'dist/assets/app_components/css/default_css.css'],
                dest: '.tmp/concat/assets/app_components/css/default_css.css'
            }
        },

        useminPrepare: {
            html: 'dist/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: 'dist/',
                root: 'site_dev/'
            }
        },

        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                options: {
                    optimizationLevel: 3,
                    cache: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'site_dev/assets/app_components/img/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif,PNG,JPG,GIF}'],
                    dest: 'dist/assets/app_components/img/'
                }]
            }
        },

        preprocess : {
            html : {
                src : ['dist/*.html'],
                options: {
                    inline : true
                }
            }
        },

        usemin: {
            html: 'dist/index.html'
        }

    });

    // Load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-preprocess');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default',
        [
            // first check to know if JS is ok
            'jshint',
            'clean:site_prod',
            'copy:dev_to_prod',
            'copy:keep_fonts_font_awesome',
            'copy:keep_dist_fonts_bootstrap',
            'copy:keep_dist_img_bootstrap',
            'replace:less_in_html',
            'less:less_to_css_prod',
            'preprocess:html',
            'useminPrepare',
            'concat:generated',
            'concat:app',
            'uglify:generated',
            'cssmin:generated',
            'replace:remove_mock_angular',
            'imagemin',
            'usemin'
        ]
    );

};
```

Comment: Shouldn't be. Can you share your build tasks?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using ngAnnotate?

Comment: @ThomasRoch i've just added my grunt file

Comment: @skolsuper i'd like to know what's behind. I mean ... It's not that complicated to keep a clean code and it works well for the rest of my controllers/factories. So why isn't it working for config ?

Comment: @ThomasRoch i made a web template to kick start my angular projects.
It's available here : https://github.com/maxime1992/webTemplate if you want the whole project. But i do not load a view inside the web template so it works well when minified. I used this base for an other project which loads views and after compiling with grunt i have the errors in config because minification failed here, as i explained in the post.

Comment: I made a little mistake in the minification result. See edit 2. It's not ``app.config(["a","b", function(a, b)`` but ``app.config(["$httpProvider","$routeProvider", function(a, b)``

Comment: Call me unobservant, but what behaviour were you expecting?

Comment: @BernhardHofmann i wouldn't call you unobservant, we're here to help each others, right ? I'm expecting this output : ``app.config(["$httpProvider","$routeProvider", function($httpProvider, $routeProvider)``

Comment: @Maxime `app.config(["$httpProvider","$routeProvider", function(a, b)` is correct. The `a` and `b` are "minified" names for `$httpProvider` and `$routeProvider` inside the config function.

Comment: @miensol i guess i misunderstood something. Maybe that's what Bernhard was trying to say. In fact, when i load my view i have the following errors (screen capture) : http://hpics.li/f1612c7 . Maybe i was not looking in the right direction and the problem is something else.

Comment: @Maxime well the error in the screenshot is pretty clear: Angular can't load template from given url

Comment: @miensol I have no idea why ... The structure remains the same. And pages are in the view folder. It works well before minification. Any idea ?

Comment: You're using `usmin` and it most likely causes the `*html` files to get `revved` for caching purposes. Check the file names in dist folder.

Comment: Your minification (after edit) is correct. You can also bundle your HTML files with html2js.

Comment: @miensol files seem ok in dist folder : Name and content checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED :

The issue here seems to be ngMock being loaded in production environment, blocking the requests to load the templates. You should remove the ngMock dependency file when packaging you application

Comment: Please have a look to comments. It seems that the problem is not with injections but to get the views.

Comment: "Unexpected request" error looks a lot like ngMock error when executing a request that is not expected... May it be that your are aggregating the ngMock test module when packaging ?

Comment: I remove ngMock from module dependencies and i do not concat my mock file into my final app.js. So i guess you're right. But still, i don't understand why i can't load a page html (which exists).

Comment: myProdEnv/assets/path-to-template-i-cant-copy-from-image.html does return the template when opening url from a browser ?

Comment: Yes, i can open the HTML page i'm looking for if i put the good path in url.

Comment: Ok, weird behavior. My mock file is : ``app.run(function($httpBackend) { $httpBackend.whenGET('GET/listeArticles').respond(listArticles); $httpBackend.whenGET(/\/views\//).passThrough(); });`` In dev env, if i remove ``$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/views\//).passThrough(); });`` i have the same error of prod env.

Comment: ngMock doesnt need to be added as dependency to add mock behaviour, if I remenber correctly. You should exclude the dependency file.

Comment: but more globally, ngMock should only used for unit test ( or eventually 'e2e'  tests ), but NEVER loaded on your application. You should also check plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates , which is just a must-have for packaging an angular app.

Comment: I need to mock http response in dev. So i use ngMock. When i want to go on prod, i use grunt. In my grunt, i remove the ngMock dependencie and my mock file. So i do not have anything mocked in prod.

Comment: But as i said, you think the error may be coming from mock. So i dig a little bit in this direction and i found out that if i remove in my project (in dev) the ``$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/views\//).passThrough(); });`` of my mock file, i have the same error that i have in prod. But i can't figure out why ..

Comment: because ngMock will not accept to let pass ANY request that is not verobosely declared with whenGET, whenPOST and so on... this is a test tool, not a local environnement mock to avoid hitting the backend...

Comment: so as i said, I'm pretty sure you do are loading ngMock in your prod environnement. Just try this in the console : $("[ng-app]").injector().get("$httpBackend").whenPOST . if it returns a method instead of undefined, you do are loading ngMock.

Comment: DAAAAAAAMN you're right ... I spent so much time on that ! I forgot the ``<!-- @ifdef DEBUG --> <!-- @endif -->`` in my html to delete the import of angular-mocks.js when i grunt ! I would never have found that without you, thank you so much !

Comment: edit your answer and precise that i need to remove angular-mock, i'll edit my question to let other people know the problem was not what i think at first and i'll accept your answer as solution :)